# How can I start a transitions between two animations using a bool parameter in my script?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I added a transition between Walk and Idle and added a new parameter name Idle type bool. In the transition I set Has Exit Time to false and then in the Conditions I added the Idle parameter set it to false.

[image: Transition]

But when running the game the transition is working even if the Idle parameter is set to false.

I want that in my script in some specific condition the transition will start between the Walk and Idle.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnimatorController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator[] animators;
    public Transform target;
    public float speed = 1f;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    public bool slowDown = false;

    private bool endRot = false;
    private Vector3 center;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        center = target.GetComponent<Renderer>().bounds.center;

        for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float distanceFromTarget = Vector3.Distance(animators[2].transform.position, target.position);

        for(int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
        {
            animators[2].transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(animators[2].transform.position, center, 0);
        }

        if (slowDown)
        {
            if (distanceFromTarget < 10)
            {
                float speed = (distanceFromTarget / 10) / 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", speed);
                }
            }
        }

        if (distanceFromTarget < 3.5f)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
            {
                animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
            }

            if (!endRot)
            {
                Quaternion goalRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, 180f, 0f);
                float angleToGoal = Quaternion.Angle(
                        goalRotation,
                        animators[0].transform.localRotation);
                float angleThisFrame = Mathf.Min(angleToGoal, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);

                // use axis of Vector3.down to keep angles positive for ease of use
                animators[0].transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, angleThisFrame);
                animators[1].transform.Rotate(Vector3.down, angleThisFrame);

                // We end if we rotated the remaining amount.
                endRot = (angleThisFrame == angleToGoal);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want that instead stop the object here:

```
if (distanceFromTarget < 3.5f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetFloat("Walking Speed", 0);
                }
```

To slowly smooth change between walking and idle.
The transition is working fine in the editor but I want it to start only when the distance is less then 3.5 and now when running the game the transition is starting much faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not telling your animator to do the transition and change the animation.

First, you want to change the transition condition to True. Otherwise, you are telling the animator: My object is not idle, however, start the idling animation (and you defaulted to false, that means that it will always going to be idling).

Second, you want to tell the animator what the state of the object is using your bool.

```
if (distanceFromTarget < 3.5f)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < animators.Length; i++)
                {
                    animators[i].SetBool("Idle", true);
                }
```

You may want to restart the Movement animation somewhere else when the object is actually moving. For that, you will need a transition from Idle to Movement, and follow the same logic.

I am not to sure about the smooth transition statement if what you want to do is a slower transition.